# Buscar dato en ASP.NET MVC SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de crear un buscador que me traiga datos desde `SQL` en `MVC`. 
Es decir, quiero que mi página principal tenga un `TextBox` y el `Botón` buscar. 
En la `BD` está declarado que el tipo de valor sea `Double`. 
Entonces, me gustaría saber como puedo arreglar el código porque de la siguiente manera me dice que la entrada de valores `Double` no permite null.

Clase ConexionSQL:

```
public void buscadorTitulo(double titu) {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("string cadena conexion");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,max(Cuota) FROM V_CuetaWeb WHERE titulo = " + titu);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(0));
                string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                double cuota = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(2));
                Cuotas p = new Cuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index(double buscar)
        {
            ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
            cn.buscadorTitulo(buscar);
            return View();
        }
```

Vista:

```
<div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("buscar")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print()" />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia o corrección?e

Comment: Donde te da el error, y que error te da?. Edita la pregunta e indica el error por favor.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: El error me da cuando intento compilar. Empieza a cargar la página y muestra el error que mencioné de nulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es permitir valores nulos en un `double`, debes hacer que el parámetro sea `Nullable` con `double?`:

```
public void buscadorTitulo(double? titu)
```

y

```
public ActionResult Index(double? buscar)
```